# Setting headers in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to make a json request to laravel from a different URL and am getting the following error back:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.core/v1.0/accounting/items/. Origin http://site.dev is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I tried setting this in my after filter with no luck. I am using NGINX:

```
App::after(function($request, $response)
{
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    return $response;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you must set that header on .htaccess file if using Apache,
or use option --disable-web-security if using chrome browser.

Please read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin).

nginx configuration:

> add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the code in the before filter `App::before`

Answer (score 0):

In your after filter yoy can directly use php's header method to set the headers

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
```

Comment: Also, it's not a method, it's a global function.